# Check if Server is up without exception

Tags: java, android, sockets, client-server

I would like to check if a certain IP-Port is open in Java for an android application.

This is the code that calls:

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                RetreiveFeedTask Check=new RetreiveFeedTask();
                try{
                Work=(Check.execute(Exec, ServerIP, ServerPort)).get();
                ALL.setText(Work);//Display what is returned
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {e.printStackTrace(); }
                if(Work.equal("xyz")
                {
                    //Do Stuff
                }
                else 
                {
                                     //Do Other Stuff
                }

            }
        });
```

Async Code:

```
class RetreiveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String , String , String > {

    //private Exception e;
    String GotBack="3";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try{        
        Socket s= new Socket(params[1], Integer.parseInt(params[2]));
        s.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); return "3";}


        try{ 
                Socket socket = new Socket(params[1], Integer.parseInt(params[2]));  
                PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());    
                BufferedReader input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                output.println(params[0]);
                output.flush();
                String read="";
                while((read=input.readLine())!=null)
                {
                GotBack=read;

                }

                socket.close();
                }
            catch(SocketException e){e.printStackTrace(); }
            catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

        return GotBack;
    }
}
```

Currently, the button freezes when I press on it...

I check if {ServerIP1-ServerPort1} accepts connections, if not I need to know.

Comment: Hard to imagine your app "freezes". If so, it's because of code which you didn't include in your question. Besides, what do you mean by "freezes"?

Comment: no no freezes as in the button stays pressed. I am sure it is cause of the exception. Because when the main server is up everything is normal...

Comment: Why don't you add e.printStackTrace() to your empty catch clause so you can see what's going on.

Comment: "the button", well, what kind of button is it? If it's a pushbutton and stays pressed then I presume you're performin an endless loop or wait on the main thread or something? As I said, the reason for this lies outside the code snippet you posted.

Comment: The main thread calls it using: Work=(Check.execute(Exec, ServerIP, ServerPort)).get();

I am sure the error is part of the snippet I provided.
If not, please let me know where I can find if it didnt connect. All I want is to find out where to replace the IP and Port with the Ip and port of the Backup Server and let it retry

Comment: My friend, if you have a button which visually remains in pressed state, then you must have a severe design flaw somewhere, and _definitely_ outside of your code snippet, and also totally unrelated to the connection error you get. But you seem to know better, so good luck.

Comment: I answered on your other Q the folloing: Well ok I probably misinterpreted your naming conventions. Usually, variable names do not start with capital letters. Assuming that `Work` is an instance of `RetrieveFeedTask`, now we know why your button stays in pressed state, namely you're waiting on the main thread by calling `get` on the `AsyncTask`. That's _not_ how to do it. Instead, you move all your result processing code to `onPostExecute()` in your `AsyncTask`.

Comment: If the main server is up, this method performs all well. I just want it to return "3" if connection of the IP-port provided to Async fails to connect...

Comment: Yeah good luck with your "all well performing method". It takes a bit more than a lack of syntax errors to get an Android app going. But you seem to think you don't even have to read the most basic tutorials. Have fun!

Comment: @ClassStacker thanks for all the fuss my friend :)
The mistake was from the way I am initializing my socket and nothing related to all of what you said...
Think before attacking next time!

Comment: "the mistake", haha. Well I guess for you the most important aspect of this all is that you enjoy what you think is programming. Ignorance is bliss, and have fun man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed that you call your Asynctask twice, first with the normal server and a second time with the backup server. Now try this, and start your AsyncTask specifying both servers and both ports, i.e. 
BackgroundTask(NrmSrvAddress, NrmSrvPort, bckSrvAddress, bckSrvPort);
Then use the following function to connect to the server(s):
(I have not run the code, it's just an idea)

```
public Socket ConnectToServer(String normalSrv, int nrmPort, String backupSrv, int bckPort)
{
    // Let's try to connect to the Normal Server first.
    try
    {
        Socket retSocket = new Socket();
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(normalSrv);
        SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(addr, nrmPort);
        retSocket.connect(sockaddr, 30000); // 30 seconds timeout
        return retSocket;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // can't connect to the Normal Server
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Normal server is down, let's try to connect to the Backup Server.
    try
    {
        Socket retSocket = new Socket();
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(backupSrv);
        SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(addr, bckPort);
        retSocket.connect(sockaddr, 30000); // 30 seconds timeout
        return retSocket;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // can't connect to the Backup Server
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // none of the server are available
    return null;
}

// Then, in your AsyncTask:
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    Socket socket = ConnectToServer(params[1], Integer.parseInt(params[2]), params[3], Integer.parseInt(params[4]));
    if (socket != null) 
    {
        try{ 
               PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());    
               BufferedReader input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
               output.println(params[0]);
               output.flush();
               String read="";
               while((read=input.readLine())!=null)
               {
                  TheData=read;
               }
            }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally 
        { 
            socket.close();                                                 
        }
        return TheData;
```

Oh, I see, you try to execute an AsyncTask in the OnClick event and want the Main thread to wait until it's finished? That's not the way AsyncTask are used. You should use the onPostExecute method of the AsyncTask to process the return value. That's why your button freezes.

I can suggest the following:

1. Create a new thread in the button's OnClick event. If you want to go with AsyncTask anyway, then read about it and how it works.
2. In that thread (or background process) try to connect to the "normal server" and if it's fails try the backup server.

The main idea is on the code I posted before "ConnectToServer", you have to parts, first one try to connect to the normal server and return the socket it gets, instead of returning the socket just do the reading right there. If it fails to connect then do the same on the part of the backup server.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I tried it but still same problem, gets stuck

Comment: Read my answer again, I added some more lines.

Answer (score 0):

How about catching the `java.net.SocketException` exception in your client code. If the server is down, you should get a `SocketException` depending on that you can then decide to connect to the secondary server.